# Several problems with Onedrive for business in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1. My university provides Office 365 which includes Onedrive for business. I recently reinstalled Office 365 because the Onedrive for business window kept opening generating several icons in the taskbar and I had synchronization problems. Now, no file is being synchronized. I tried to restore but I got an error: some files are open. This is not true and I get this error even if I restart Windows and try to restore after the restart. If I try to sync by dragging  each folder in the browser app, it says that I can upload empty folders (which are not). 
Some notes:

- My onedrive for business is linked to my University account and not my windows account
- I already cleared the Office cache as suggested in an article that I read
- The icon of Onedrive for business in the taskbar says: "Synchronizing - 14 files left" but it is stuck in this state and nothing happens

If you have any suggestion, please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I deleted all files both locally and from the server and I moved them to Onedrive, which works fine. Now Onedrive for business started working and the files are appearing back even if I deleted it...I am a bit confused.

Comment: Try right clicking the OneDrive for Business icon in the system tray and clicking "Stop syncing a folder...". You should be able to stop your OneDrive from syncing to your computer; you can then try re-syncing by clicking "Sync" in the OneDrive for Business web interface. We use OneDrive for Business at the University I work for and we experience the odd time this happens too.

Comment: You should also check to make sure that there isn't a file that OneDrive doesn't like. If you have an exe for example on the local side, it won't sync.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I solve the problem?